# Entries object getting reset after a relatedTo query

Tags: templating, entries, craft3

This is from a template that worked in Craft 2, but doesn't in Craft 3.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.type('publications').orderBy("postDate desc") %}
```

entries.count() outputs 80

```
{% for cat in allCats %}
    {% set catEntries = entries.relatedTo(cat) %}
    {% if catEntries | length or cat.slug=="all" or cat.slug=="toutes" %}
        <li><a href="{{ cat.url }}" {% if category is defined and cat.slug == category.slug %}class="current"{% endif %}>{{ cat.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This iterates through all categories with correct entries associated

After that, entries.count() outputs 0

Looks like entries is getting set to the last value instead of just passing the resulting object to the variable.  This is not how it worked before.  Is there a way to reset this ?

Comment: Probably a dupe of https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25613/missing-matrix-row-types-on-output-after-upgrade-to-craft-3-subsetting-and-clon ?

Comment: Hi @BradBell, I agree that it most be a dupe question, but the answer is not available where it ends up linking.
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#cloning-element-queries

Would you care to give a proper answer and/or link to the actual explanation and how to get it done?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/templating/functions.html#clone-object please take a look at the comments https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2160

Answer (score 1):

Based on the bug report found here (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2160), I am now creating a variable that contains all of the items prior to filtering it.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.type('publications').orderBy("postDate desc") %}
{% set allEntries = entries.all() %}
```

I can then use entries to filter through the available categories and then use allEntries to loop through all of them.

I understand I could also have used clone() to get a copy to work from in my category loop.

```
{% set catEntries = clone(entries).relatedTo(cat) %}
```