# Matrix field not displaying all blocks on Craft 3 Upgrade

Tags: matrix, craft3

Just upgraded a website for the first time to Craft 3.
I had a matrix field called bodyContent which is basically my page builder.
Issue is not when creating new pages it the only blocks it seems to pick up are the Redactor Field Blocks -

Plain text, fields not nothing else display on the front end.

On my template pages if I try to find the number of blocks -

```
{{ entry.bodyContent|length }
```

It displays say only 2 if there are 2 rich text fields - it seems to ignore the rest.

Other blocks are generic headers, plain text fields, assets fields for images/documents etc.

But when I view the entry int he CMS all the blocks are still there - though they don't display in Live Preview either.

Really not sure even where to start with this one.  Tried resaving the Matrix Field etc but no success.

Edit - 
After some more searching thinking it may be related to this:
[Missing Matrix row types on output after upgrade to Craft 3 (subsetting and cloning ElementQueries)](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25613/missing-matrix-row-types-on-output-after-upgrade-to-craft-3-subsetting-and-clon)

Existing Code block for outputting the matrix field:

```
    {% if matrixfield is not defined %}
        {% set matrixfield=entry.bodyContent %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ matrixfield|length }}
    {% for block in matrixfield.all() %}
        {{ block.type }}
        {% include "includes/matrix-blocks/" ~ block.type %}   
    {% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**

Folliwing coments below that can use Elementquery.getRawSql() i tried the following:
Ok - on outputting: `{{ entry.bodyContent.getRawSql() }}`

I get

```
`SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`fieldLayoutId`, `elements`.`uid`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_sites`.`slug`, `elements_sites`.`uri`, `elements_sites`.`enabled` AS `enabledForSite`, `matrixblocks`.`fieldId`, `matrixblocks`.`ownerId`, `matrixblocks`.`ownerSiteId`, `matrixblocks`.`typeId`, `matrixblocks`.`sortOrder`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `content`.`field_heading_size`, `content`.`field_heading_heading`, `content`.`field_text_text`, `content`.`field_image_caption`, `content`.`field_image_position`, `content`.`field_video_videoUrl`, `content`.`field_gallery_layout`, `content`.`field_gallery_galleryType`, `content`.`field_textImageSection_sectionHeading`, `content`.`field_textImageSection_imageColumnPosition`, `content`.`field_textImageSection_imageFullHeight`, `content`.`field_textImageSection_text`, `content`.`field_textImageSection_imageColumnWidth`, `content`.`field_textImageSection_lightboxOnImage`, `content`.`field_staticBlock_staticBlock`, `content`.`field_plainTextHtml_plainTextHtml` FROM (SELECT `elements`.`id` AS `elementsId`, `elements_sites`.`id` AS `elementsSitesId`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId` FROM `craft_elements` `elements` INNER JOIN `craft_matrixblocks` `matrixblocks` ON `matrixblocks`.`id` = `elements`.`id` INNER JOIN `craft_elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id` INNER JOIN `craft_matrixcontent_bodycontent` `content` ON `content`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id` WHERE (`matrixblocks`.`fieldId`='16') AND (`matrixblocks`.`ownerId`='109') AND (`matrixblocks`.`typeId`='3') AND (`elements_sites`.`siteId`=1) AND (`content`.`siteId`=1) AND (`elements`.`archived`=FALSE) ORDER BY `matrixblocks`.`sortOrder`) `subquery` INNER JOIN `craft_matrixblocks` `matrixblocks` ON `matrixblocks`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId` INNER JOIN `craft_elements` `elements` ON `elements`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId` INNER JOIN `craft_elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsSitesId` INNER JOIN `craft_matrixcontent_bodycontent` `content` ON `content`.`id` = `subquery`.`contentId` ORDER BY `matrixblocks`.`sortOrder`
```

Near the end of that I notice a bit

```
AND (`matrixblocks`.`typeId`='3')
```

Is that only pulling in the block of 1 type?

**Update**
In my header I had been pulling in a meta description with the code:

```
{% if entry.bodyContent|length %}
   {% set customdescription = entry.bodyContent.type('text').one()|striptags|slice(0, 155) %}
{% endif %}
```

Which was manipulating for the code below. I resolved by using the clone option in my header like below:

```
{% set bodycontent = entry.bodyContent %}
{% if bodycontent|length %}
   {% set customdescription = clone(bodycontent).type('text').one()|striptags|slice(0, 155) %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Do you receive the correct blocks when you append a `status(null).enabledForSite(false)` to the query?

Comment: Thanks - but that made no difference - just my text blocks displayed again.

Comment: Then there must be something wrong at some other point in your code. Maybe you manipulate those variables before? If it's visible in the CP it must be accessible

Comment: It was working fine in Craft 2 - I've tried just outputting directly on the page as opposed to the above code which is in an include - but still getting the same. {{ entry.bodyContent|length}} is still only dislaying 2.

Comment: You can get the raw sql and check if there are certain conditions attached that doesn't match via `ElementQuery.getRawSql()`

Comment: see update in question - see a bit in query `AND ('matrixblocks'.'typeId'='3')`

Comment: As I said you manipulate your query at some point. You either need to use the copy function or reset the property

Comment: Ok - in my header at the top to get a metadescription I have `{% set customdescription = entry.bodyContent.type('text').one()|striptags|slice(0, 155) %}` if I comment that out all blocks are displayed - thanks

Comment: Do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: Just want to say this comment / thread has saved me such a headache - i couldn't work out why my matrix blocks were not being output correctly, and going round in circles! sure enough i was doing some manipulation to the query elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manipulate your query somewhere else in the code those properties will not reset after you execute it. You'll either reset the properties (for example `query.typeId(null).all()` or you need the `clone` [function](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#cloning-element-queries)